# Resample point source to image data in ParaView

Tags: visualization, sampling, paraview

How to resample a polygonal mesh containing just points (in one cell -> Point Source) to an image data set in ParaView. I am using the [Resample to Image](https://blog.kitware.com/dataset-resampling-filters/) filter from the upcoming ParaView version 5.2.

All resampled data arrays have a range of [0,0] instead of their expected values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sample a point source to vtkImageData, use the [Point Interpolation Filters](https://blog.kitware.com/point-and-smoothed-particle-hydrodynamics-sph-interpolation-in-paraview/) instead. **Point Volume Interpolator** is what you want.

Comment: Just for information for other readers: The point interpolation filters are part of the ParaView 5.1 release.

Comment: A bit more information on why one works and the other does not. Resample to Image filter takes a regular collection of points and for each point finds the cell in the input that contains it to get field values. When you have a meshless collection of points as you do, Resample to Image filter treats that as empty space between the points, which is why you get 0 for all the scalar values. In contrast, the Point Interpolation Filters interpret the input data as a meshless collection of samples. It interpolates the field values by estimating the probability based on the input points.